# Chrome Extension - How to send cookies in a request?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have read tons of SO and no luck. How do I send cookies in API requests from chrome extension?
I want to make a post request to my API through chrome extension. But, the API is protected. Luckily, I can get the cookie for the API if I am already logged into my app with `chrome.cookie`. But, how do you attach that cookie to the API request?

I can get the cookie of the website with `chrome.cookie`, but how do I attach that cookie to the API request?

Comment: The cookie is sent automatically, usually, if you add the site to host_permissions in manifest.json. Don't forget to reload the extension after editing. If the problem isn't solved, please show [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question i.e. the code, where it runs, how the file is loaded/declared.

Comment: Wow, @wOxxOm. Thank you so much!!! I have been banging my head over this.